# Grouping by or iterating through partitions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, partitioning

Two part question regarding partitioning in SQL.

In T-SQL when you use PARTITION BY is there a way to assign a unique number to each partition, in addition to something like row_number()?

E.g. row_number() would yield,

```
Action          Timestamp           RowNum
A               '2013-1-10'         1
A               '2013-1-11'         2
B               '2013-1-12'         1
B               '2013-1-13'         2
```

Whereas, in addition, uniquely identifying each partition could yield,

```
Action          Timestamp           RowNum          PartitionNum
A               '2013-1-10'         1               1
A               '2013-1-11'         2               1
B               '2013-1-12'         1               2
B               '2013-1-13'         2               2
```

Then one could GROUP BY partition number.

Second part of my question is, how can you break out each partition and iterate through it, e.g.,

```
for each partition p
   for each row r in p 
       do F(r)
```

Any way in T-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dense_rank()`:

```
select  *
,       row_number() over (partition by Action order by Timestamp) as RowNum
,       dense_rank() over (order by Action) as PartitionNum
from    YourTable
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4f6a/2/0)

T-SQL is not good at iterating, but if you really have to, check out [cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190028%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: There's a nuance here I didn't realize at first, where dense_rank doesn't need the results partitioned to achieve the desired effect, just an ordered result set!