# Computed column that uses row_number() or dense_rank() over a partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, partitioning, sql-function

This question is related to a previous question, 
[Grouping by or iterating through partitions in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660169/grouping-by-or-iterating-through-partitions-in-sql)

I need to support SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, and cannot depend on the Enterprise or full version (must work in SQL Server Express).

What I am trying to do is create a user-defined **computed** column that is essentially either a `row_number()` or `dense_rank()` over a partition by clause. This needs to act like an index, in that whenever rows are added to the table, this user-defined column is automatically generated.

I looked over the following Microsoft link that explains how to create a column based on a function, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx. It doesn't quite get there.

It may not be possible, especially without the full version of SQL Server. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you looking for how to write the udf, or the DDL syntax to create the column?  Also, can you be more specific on what the logic for this column would be?

Comment: I think my questions is more conceptual, e.g whether this is even possible or even an existing practice? I know of partitioned tables, but that requires the enterprise edition, so this could be seen as a sort of poor-mans partitioned tables. Anyways I am more concerned with the UDF, rather than the DDL syntax. The logic is to create an integer which represents the row number within a partition that any given row belongs to.

Comment: Conceptually it can probably be done, and the enterprise edition is identical to the express edition in terms of functionality.  The differences are in the non-TSQL 'features' such as moving data across machines, and using more disk space, memory, and CPUs.  Whether it can be done in your case is more dependent on the specifics of what you want to do...

Comment: Also, are you expecting this calculated data to be persisted?  If so, consider that for each write, the entire table may need to be scanned to update the computations - not a great idea for OLTP systems.

Comment: This is more like a persistent data analysis / data mining app, but yeah, that is true. For now I just want to figure out if its possible. I think constraints could be added to the UDF to improve the performance (e.g, instead of scanning the whole table, only scan a part that is constrained by a where clause, maybe). But I will worry about that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main feature of partitioning is splitting single object into multiple *relatively independent* database objects. Partitioning allows:

- switch partitions from one table to another immediately, because it becomes a meta data operation, rather than physical copy.
- lock single partition instead of the whole table, thus giving several processes simultaneous independent access to each partition.
- spread a single table over multiple db files, storing each partition in its own file
- compress data and change some other properties for each partition individually.

It cannot be done by any other means.

So I think you are looking to a way to assign an ID to each combination of some key, which consists of multiple columns. There is a number of ways to do it, depending on the result you want to achieve:

- Create an index on several columns. It may be clustered, it may be on primary key columns. It will aid searches and get you data sorted (in case of clustered index).
- Create separate table with all your primary key columns and assign each combination a unique key (eg using `IDENTITY` property). Insert this key to your main table to use as "partition id". Insert values automatically using a trigger or a join.

Please note, that SQL Server can use only one column for partitioning.