# SQL query to find new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help. I have a table named Test_Result with 2 columns as shown below.

```
ID  Source_ID
10  1
20  2
30  2
40  3 
50  3
60  3
70  4
```

I am trying to get output as below,but unable to get logic.

```
ID  Parent_ID   Source_ID
10   Null         1
20   Null         2
30   20           2
40   Null         3
50   40           3
60   50           3
70   Null         4
```

Kindly help me with this scenario. I attached question in picture for as well.

Regards,
Abhi

[image]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags. Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: if you are using SQL Server,simple `Lag()OVER(Partition By)` could solve your problem

Comment: In this problem basically all first element for Parent is null where source is same. am I correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660169/grouping-by-or-iterating-through-partitions-in-sql check this link

Comment: For first element yes the parent will be null but for the rest logic has to derived.

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

These solutions (ROW_NUMBER/LAG) will work for MySQL 8.0+ or MariaDB 10.2

You could use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) and join to previous row:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(ID INT  ,Source_ID INT);

INSERT INTO tab(id, Source_id)
SELECT 10,  1
UNION ALL SELECT 20 , 2
UNION ALL SELECT 30,  2
UNION ALL SELECT 40 , 3 
UNION ALL SELECT 50 , 3
UNION ALL SELECT 60 , 3
UNION ALL SELECT 70 , 4;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM tab
)
SELECT c1.ID,
       CASE WHEN c1.Source_ID = c2.Source_ID  THEN c2.Id END AS Parent_Id,
       c1.Source_ID
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.rn = c2.rn+1;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/GHRWUD42725)**

**EDIT:**

Using `LAG()` windowed function:

```
SELECT c1.ID,
  CASE 
    WHEN c1.Source_ID = LAG(Source_ID) OVER w THEN LAG(ID) OVER w 
  END AS Parent_Id,
  c1.Source_ID
FROM tab c1
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ID)
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=17d4f1c0057133c22eac957f78f95fa9)**

---

**EDIT2:**
Simulating `LAG` using variables:

```
SET @lag_Source_id='';
SET @lag_Id = '';

SELECT ID, 
       CASE WHEN Source_Id = lag_Source_ID THEN lag_ID END AS Parent_ID
       ,Source_ID
FROM (
    SELECT ID
    , Source_ID
    , @lag_Source_id AS lag_Source_id
    , @lag_Source_id:= Source_ID AS curr_Source_ID
    , @lag_Id AS lag_ID
    , @lag_Id := ID AS curr_ID 
    FROM tab
    ORDER BY id
) AS sub
```

**[RextesterDemo2](http://rextester.com/JCHT26153)**

Comment: I am running it on mysql so don't think WITH cte work.

Comment: CTE/ROW_NUMBER are available from MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB (http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=97e923ea97dd6a1f82921678175052af)

Comment: Unable to : getting error as, Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WITH cte AS (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rn
     FROM tab

Comment: even edited is not working. Giving error on function used. Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION LAG does not exist

Comment: @Abhi Please specify your version of MySQL in question. `select version() as 'mysql version'`

Comment: version is 5.1.73

Comment: Tha Edit2 is ging parent_id as null for all records

Comment: @Abhi All my solutions works. Please see demos. I cannot guess what data you have so I cannot help more.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mysql database simply do this,

```
SELECT ID, (ID + Source_ID) AS Parent_ID,   Source_ID FROM tableName LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: We need to create parent_id field using some logic.

Comment: LOGIC: if parent_id does not exist on the table initially, you need to resolve some value as the parent_id. e.g SELECT ID, (ID + Source_ID) As Parent_ID, Source_ID FROM tableName LIMIT 10

Comment: for record 1st, if source_id is 1 then parent_id will be null because it is the first and single unique source_id. For record 2nd, if we have 2 source_id here 2 then for row 2 the parent ID will be null because it is first record of that group and 3rd record will have parent id as 20. same goes with rest. Please let me know if still it is not clear.